# Using (preferably Hazelcast) distributed synchronization primitives for efficiently synchronizing MySQL Table access

Tags: java, mysql, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I have a MySQL DB table with about 100k - 200k rows. The table rows are created, updated, deleted frequently every 5-10 seconds. Currently a single JVM app instance reads all the rows and processes all the entities in the table which are found to be in a specific state. The processing task is scheduled every 1-2 minutes and processing itself takes about 1-2 minutes. Now I want to make this JVM app a clustered fault tolerant service. One option is to have multiple instances acquire a distributed Hazelcast lock, and whichever instance acquires the lock processes the entities. However ideally I would want all the JVM instances partaking in the service to be processing some of the rows but at the same time ensure that each row is processed at least once in a given 5 minute interval.

Is there a way I can use Hazelcast to shard the responsibility for a subset of table rows among multiple node instances ?

PS : Replacing MySQL is not an option, open source alternatives to Hazelcast are an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think solving the problem of this case with Hazelcast distributed lock is unnecessary.

Quartz is best option for your problem.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/